# No output shown

Tags: java

I'm writing a code which has to calculate the sum of integers from 1 to 10 , from 20 to 30, from 35 to 45 respectively.

So far I have the bellow code which compiles without any error but no output:

```
public class SumCalculator {
      public static void main(String args[]){
      sum();
   }
public static void sum() {
      int sum = 0;
      for(int num = 0; num > 11; num++) {
            sum += num; 
            System.out.printf("%d", sum);
      }
     }
}
```

any help?

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Please review [How to ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is a polite way of saying you have to invest a minimum amount of effort that is not evident here.

Comment: That's some pretty short code.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a **specific problem** with the **complete error message and/or stacktrace** and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Stepping through this code in a debugger should *immediately* show you the problem.  Stack Overflow is not a replacement for a debugger.

Comment: Even [talking to a rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would have solved this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use num <11 instead of num > 11. Your for loop is not getting executed because of this error.

Comment: Thank you very much did not notice it.

Answer (score 2):

This segment is killing your code:

```
for (int num = 0; num > 11; num++) {
```

as you can see **num** is initialized to zero and you are asking the program to do the loop **while** **num>11**

such a contradiction is making your code to skip the for loop
hence no print and no addition as well

Change it to:

```
for (int num = 0; num < 10; num++) {
...
```

and later change the values for the next ranges

```
for (int num = 20; num < 30; num++) {
...
etc etc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
        sum(1, 6);
        sum(20, 30);
        sum(35, 45);
    }

    public static void sum(int a, int b) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int num = a; num <= b; num++) {
            sum += num;
        }
        System.out.printf("\n%d", sum);
    }
```

Don't hardcode.